# OSX 10.9 Sending files to a windows network drive

Tags: network, file-transfer

I have a mapped network drive on a windows tower. I can connect to it, I can read from it. I can't send files to it, though.

When I try and drag them from the finder window into the network drive window, nothing happens. Why is that?

Notes:

- All users who access the drive have full read write permissions
- I even logged in as the tower's administrator
- I have SMB enabled in sharing

Do I need to list the folder im trying to drag to the network drive?

Comment: What do you mean by "mapped network drive"—that's not OS X terminology I'm used to (mapping a network drive on Windows refers to equating a drive (like M:) to a network share. On OS X, you would **mount** a network share. It does this automatically when you browse or go to it.

Comment: When you accessed the drive through Finder, did you have to provide credentials?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the flawed SMB2 implementation in Mavericks. Try connecting to the share using cifs://server/share instead of smb:// and this will force the connection to use SMB1 which should be more compatible.